# An issue about singleton

Tags: android, singleton

I take a reference with http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-2/
I find that if i use the code , i can't show the notification

```
if (Config.appendNotificationMessages) {//it's true
            //store the notification in shared pref first
            MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefManager().addNotification(message);
            //get the notification from shared preferences
            String oldNotification = MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefManager().getNotifications();

            List<String> messages = Arrays.asList(oldNotification.split("\\|"));//待看

            for (int i = messages.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                inboxStyle.addLine(messages.get(i));
                System.out.println("for");
            }
        } else {
            inboxStyle.addLine(message);
        }
```

it will show error `MyApplication.getPrefManager()' on a null object reference`

It's my MyApplication.class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static final String TAG = MyApplication.class.getSimpleName();

    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    private MyPreferenceManager pref;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public MyPreferenceManager getPrefManager() {
        if (pref == null) {
            pref = new MyPreferenceManager(this);
        }
        return pref;
    }
}
```

How do i fix the issue ? Any help would be appreciated .

Here is MyPreferenceManager

```
public class MyPreferenceManager {
    private String TAG = MyPreferenceManager.class.getSimpleName();

    //Shared Preference
    SharedPreferences pref;

    //Editor for shared preference
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    //Context
    Context context;

    //Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    //SharedPref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "androidhive_gcm";

    //All Shared Preferences key
    private static final String KEY_USER_ID = "user_id";
    private static final String KEY_USER_NAME = "user_name";
    private static final String KEY_USER_EMAIL = "user_email";
    private static final String KEY_NOTIFICATIONS = "notifications";


    //Constructor
    public MyPreferenceManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void addNotification(String notification) {
        //get old notifications
        String oldNotifications = getNotifications();

        if (oldNotifications != null) {
            oldNotifications += "|" + notification;
        } else {
            oldNotifications = notification;
        }
        editor.putString(KEY_NOTIFICATIONS, oldNotifications);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getNotifications() {
        return pref.getString(KEY_NOTIFICATIONS, null);
    }

    public void clear() {
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a wrong place to implement the getPrefrerenceManager. This singleton pattern should be applied in MyPreferenceManager class instead.

Comment: Looking from this only code seems you missed passing context ,
`getPrefManager(Context mContext)` and then use it in line `pref = new MyPreferenceManager(mContext);`

Comment: @MKJParekh How do i set context in this line `String oldNotification=MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefManager().getNotifications();` ?   They are in my NotificationUtils class extends nothing

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35765226/3111083 . Change your getInstance method to this and check. Reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern.

Comment: @sunilsunny , thanks for your information ,i had try it , it still shows the same error.

Comment: @徐博俊, can you please post MyPreferenceManager class? Here singleton class in not implemented properly.

Comment: sure , but i fix the issue from others suggestion , thanks all of you guys , i just focused on Context , the problem would be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to make the Application class singleton if it only for getting a shared preference instance. If you want to get a singleton pattern applied in your shared preference, do this on the shared preference related class instead of the Application class.

From the look of it, you're using `MyPreferenceManager` class to contain all shared preference related codes. So, I'd say, make it singleton instead.

```
public class MyPreferenceManager {
    //Applying Singleton
    private static MyPreferenceManager pref;

    private MyPreferenceManager(){}

    public static MyPreferenceManager getPrefManager(Context context) {
        if (pref == null) {
            pref = new MyPreferenceManager(context);
        }
        return pref;
    }

    /*
    * Implementation of addNotification, getNotification and other methods
    */

}
```

And call it like this

```
//store the notification in shared pref first
MyPreferenceManager.getPrefManager(context).addNotification(message);
//get the notification from shared preferences
String oldNotification = MyPreferenceManager.getPrefManager(context).getNotifications();
```

In `context`, pass your appropriate context depending on Activity or Fragment.

Comment: No problem. Happy to be of any help.